# 'Utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed

Tags: utf-8

```
df_track = pd.read_csv(E:/my_python/project_2/tracks.csv)
df_tracks.head()
```

This is my code, and while execution I get error

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 201994: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Note: it is not your code. Use copy/paste to copy code: often the error is just a typo which you may not copied back.

Comment: Read the file into memory in binary mode.   Go to position 201994 in the file post the raw bytes around that location.  The data there could give a hint what encoding it actually is.

Answer (score 6):

The error means that your file is not UTF-8 (a common default encoding). Maybe it is a mixed encoding file.

As you can look in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html, you have a `encoding` parameter to specify a different encoding, and you have a link to the list of supported encoding. Try with `latin1`. If the file is older, you should guess the encoding (it depends on the country, the operating system, etc.).

So try adding `, encoding='latin1'` to your `read_csv()`. It will not fail (as giving you an error message): this encoder can decode all bytes sequences. Just it may give wrong characters, and in such case try other encoding (listed in a link in the above `read_csv` documentation), until the text seems correct everywhere.

Other common encodings: `cp1252` (common for western languages in Windows), `mbcs` (it works only on Windows, it is the infamous *Windows ANSI*), `cp437` (old IBM PC), `mac_roman` for old mac (western languages).

EDITED: `latin1` seems a better solution in Python, and add a list of common encodings.

Comment: `cp1252` has five bytes that don't decode, unlike `latin1`, so it *could* fail. Try `b'\x81'.decode('cp1252')`.  `cpl1252` and `latin1` also aren't too compatible with 32 differences in decoding.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: right. I missed the five characters. CP1252 is a superset of Latin1. Latin 1 as defined in ECMA standard (created/updated for ISO), is a 96 character encoding. Further (and later standards) assigned ASCII + Latin 1 as "Latin 1" (and forbidding C1 use, as well many C0 characters). But it seems Python uses a different interpretation (it includes C1). "Latin1" is so bloated with different interpretations. But so "Latin1" in Python is possibly a good solution (but do not print in a terminal, some may interpret CSI code as CSI